# OMGWTFBBQ?!! Where's my flag weight?

Tags: support, flag-weight

I worked *sooo* hard on the flag weight & it's no longer there!!1 Where is it!? Is this a temp glitch?

Comment: You're better off for it, trust me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

waffles' just deployed a fix that has [removed the](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84859/133693) flag weight.

> Fine, I removed flag weight. It is gone.
>
> Instead you now see a count of helpful flags you raised on your user profile. You **can not** see this number on anybody else's profile, just yours.
>
> This number can be clicked to give you a breakdown of how we counted it.
>
> The 2 badges [Deputy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/140/deputy) and [Marshal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/160/marshal) were adjusted, however we did not strip any old granted badges.

Comment: See, everything is ok. ;)

Comment: @Troggy indeed ;)

Comment: 500 flags for Marshall? I was at 670ish flag weight before and now it shows I have 140flags, would it really have taken another 360 flags to get to 750 flag weight?

Comment: @Mokubai it takes about 566 flags to reach fw required gain the Marshal flag

Comment: How is this comparable? I have 41 flags now and I already had Deputy... As it is now, I would be just over half way to getting Deputy...

Comment: @RedhattedCatsaysBestWishes I'm not entirely sure - feel free to ask a new meta question on the same